# Image not showing in JFrame

Tags: java, image, jframe, imageicon

Why is my image not being displayed?  The buttons are always there, but the image does just not appear.  It may not be a programming problem.  Where should I place the image?

First Class File:

```
public class start {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        menu m1 = new menu();
        m1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Second Class File:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class menu extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public menu(){
        super("Parachute!");
        setSize(1000, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel title = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15);
        JButton play = new JButton("Play!");
        JButton help = new JButton("Help");
        JButton options = new JButton("Options");
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("parachute.jpg");
        JLabel imageLogo = new JLabel(logo);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;          

        main.add(play, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        main.add(help, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;

        main.add(options, gbc);
        title.add(imageLogo);
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: please call the constructor with Uppercase. Menu()

Comment: @AsierAranbarri He has created class `menu` not `Menu`, so `Menu()` will actually break his code.

Comment: @Ankit One thing implies the other. Classes should be named with Uppercase as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, you are not setting the layout to be borderlayout before using it. Do:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout())
```

Second, to check if the parachute.jpg file is present, you can check like this:

```
 File f = new File("parachute.jpg");
 System.out.println(f.exists());
```

If this prints `false`, it means it could not find the file. In that case , you need to put the image file in correct directory.

I believe you are using an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse. In that case, put the image in the root directory for the project. For example, you have a project `Test`. Then the image file should be in the Test folder. The IDE's generally look for files from the root of the project.

**PS**: As you are new to programming, you should try to follow the conventions of the language you are using. It makes it easy for others to understand your code. Look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for Java conventions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add main to content?
Something like this: `getcontent().add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

Comment: `getcontent` function does not exist. First, it should be `getContentPane()` and second it has nothing to do with what has been asked